# higher-order-function toList

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

How can i define a function toList equvivalent to set.toList by using set.fold or set.foldback?
I have made this function, but im very sure it's not correct.

```
let toList predicate items =
List.foldBack (fun item state ->
                match predicate item with
                | false -> state 
                | true -> item::state
              )
              items
              []
//test
toList (fun x -> x > 0) [-2;-1;0;1;2]
//output
//val toList : predicate:('a -> bool) -> items:'a list -> 'a list
//val it : int list = [1; 2]
```

Any tips/help?

Comment: For start try to replace `List.foldback` with `Set.foldback`

Comment: you example seem to work - what had you expected? - btw: this is just `List.filter` right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below should perform the same as Set.toList

```
let toList set = Set.foldBack (fun it acc -> it::acc) set []
```

Using Set.fold instead of Set.foldBack would reverse the order of the resulting list.

Your current function would have the effect of filtering a list based upon a predicate, equivalent to List.filter.